# File upload not working with navbar in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server

I can't get the File Upload feature to work properly when using a navigation bar. Here is what I have for server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)

function(input, output) {

  df <- NULL
  current_file <- NULL
  in_data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){
  return(NULL)}     
else {df <<- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
                     quote=input$quote)
      current_file <<- inFile$name
}

return(NULL)
  })


output$fileInfo <- renderTable({  
call.me = in_data()
data.frame(current_file)
})




}
```

And for ui.R I have this:

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)

navbarPage('Navigation Bar',
       tabPanel('File Information', verbatimTextOutput('fileInfo'),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                                         accept=c('text/csv', 
                                                  'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                                  '.csv')),
                    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                                 c(Comma=',',
                                   Semicolon=';',
                                   Tab='\t'),
                                 ','),
                    radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                                 c(None='',
                                   'Double Quote'='"',
                                   'Single Quote'="'"),
                                 '"'),
                    tags$hr()), 
                  mainPanel()
                )))
```

I eventually want to have multiple tabs in the navigation bar, and I want to be able to access the data from each tab. All I'm looking for it to do now is for it to give me the name of the file uploaded. This works great when I don't try to fit the navigation bar in. But now it looks like some sort of HTML output. Any tips? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is an extremely bad idea to enlist the use of the global assignment `<<-` here. Your data will be globally available to the whole app if you use a reactive -- which is the way shiny is intended to be used.

Also, look into `shiny::validate` (example usage below) to validate inputs.

```
library("shiny")

options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 9*1024^2)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # the data read in by read.csv will now be accessible throughout the app
  # by calling this reactive, e.g. in_data().
  in_data <- reactive({
    shiny::validate(
      need(input$file1, "Select a file!")
    )

    read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header = input$header,
             sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)
  })

  # an example, we're calling the reactive to access the data loaded
  output$file_info <- renderTable({
    data.frame(in_data())
  })

}

ui <- navbarPage('Navigation Bar',
  tabPanel('File Information', verbatimTextOutput('fileInfo'),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File', accept = c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')),
        checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
        radioButtons('sep', 'Separator', c(Comma = ',', Semicolon = ';', Tab = '\t'), ','),
        radioButtons('quote', 'Quote', c(None = '', 'Double Quote'='"', 'Single Quote' = "'"),'"'),
        tags$hr()
        ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("file_info")
        )
      )
    )
  )

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new to R Shiny. Why is using global variables a bad idea?

Comment: There are some situations where you do want to use globals (see http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#scoping) but in this case you definitely do not want the data from one session persisting to another. It can result in some seriously weird things depending on what you do with the data after its loaded. For instance spurious calculations could be run with the old data and the user would have no idea